# ConstraintLayout vertical align items top

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I have a simple `ConstraintLayout` inside a `RecyclerView`. The `ConstraintLayout` contains just an image and a text.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/gridRv"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/size_8dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/size_8dp"
  android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/size_8dp"/>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/size_16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/size_16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/size_8dp"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/size_8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/grid_item_state">

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/gridImage"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
      android:scaleType="centerCrop"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gridText"
      app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
      app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.45" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/gridText"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
      android:hint="@string/global_option"
      android:textColor="@color/blue_600"
      android:textFontWeight="400"
      android:maxLines="4"
      android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/gridImage" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This code produces the following:
[image: heigh:wrap_content]

I want the text to be vertically aligned to top. The text needs to start just after the image (with a small margin).

When I change the height of the `TextView` to `android:layout_height="0dp"`, I almost get the result I want. The problem here is with the `TextView` that does not scale to contain the whole text.

[image: height:0dp]

I understand why I have this issue. It's because I use `app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"`. I could use `LinearLayout` instead but I wanted `ConstraintLayout` cause I need the image to maintain it's aspect ratio while having a percentage width.

Do you guys have any suggestion how to achieve the result I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need to remove `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` from the `TextView` that makes the text just top aligned to the top image

Comment: I was not expecting to be so easy! I feel stupid. Thank you it worked like a charm! I will mark your answer as a solution as soon as the system lets me.